# rxjs concatAll() equivalent in rxjava

Tags: javascript, rx-java, rxjs

My aim is to simulate events with some random (predefined) delay.  I am simulating events in RxJs as below:

```
var events = [
     {id: 1, qty:   23, delayMs:   0},
     {id: 1, qty:  231, delayMs:   3},
     {id: 1, qty:  232, delayMs:   1},
     {id: 1, qty:  233, delayMs:   2},
     {id: 1, qty:  234, delayMs: 100},
     {id: 1, qty:  235, delayMs:  50},
     {id: 1, qty:  236, delayMs:  50},
     {id: 1, qty:  237, delayMs:  50},
     {id: 1, qty:  238, delayMs:  50},
     {id: 1, qty:  239, delayMs:  50},
     {id: 1, qty: 2310, delayMs:  50},
     {id: 1, qty: 2311, delayMs:  50},
     {id: 1, qty: 2312, delayMs: 100},
     {id: 1, qty: 2313, delayMs:  50}
 ];

var rawEvents$ = O.from(events).map(o => O.return(o).delay(o.delayMs)).concatAll();
```

With the above code, I get the simulated stream of events as expected.  I am trying to implement the same in Java, but looks like Java doesn't have concatAll().  The code that I have written so far:

```
Observable rawEvents$ = Observable.concat(Observable.from(events).map(o -> Observable.just(o).delay(o.get("delayMs"), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
```

But, since I used concat() instead of concatAll(), I was not able to output stream of events with the designated delay.  What is the equivalent of concatAll() in java?

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in RxJAva, but I think it is worth trying with `concatMap` (should be equivalent to `map(...).concatAll`). If ordering is not correct, I would try ordering the events array by increasing delay.